# upcast at runtime. (Morph from Base Class to derive Class)

Tags: php, c++, polymorphism, casting

```
class B{
  private:
    int a;
}
class D: public B{
  private:
    int b;
}

B* b = new B;
```

Now for some reason I want *turn* `b` *into* a `D*` Type of Object.
e.g. **retain** the information of B and *become* D with extra Informations required.

What I am currently thinking of is. static_cast to do the upcasting. the additional attributes will be set to null or garbage. then assign the additional attributes manually. But this leads to a dangling pointer risk. If the copy constructor is not coded with enough care.

So what else could be the proper Solution ?
**and is there any solution of the Puzzle if we think it from a PHP perspective ?**

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  There's probably a better solution than to convert a non-`D` into a `D` by casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a `static_cast<>` then the additional attributes will *not* be null or garbage, they will actually be *outside* the memory allocated for the object. Use `dynamic_cast<>`, which will properly fail if the variable does not contain the correct type.

Also, the similarity between C++ and PHP in this case is merely superficial; do not use it to gain further "insight" into the C++ code.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand what you meant by implode.  
would `dynamic_cast<>` make additional properties null or garbage ? e.g. allocate memory for it ?

Comment: Ya I know But I've to make the architecture such that i runs both as CGI on C++ as well as on PHP

Comment: If used on a pointer to an inappropriate type, `dynamic_cast<>` will return `NULL`. There is no sane way to give space for a `D` if you've only created a new `B`. Either create a new `D` in the first place, or live with the `B` you have.

Comment: Then There exists no solution in this casting way. so should I make a `template<typename From, typename To>class Adapter` Template ? or anything similer ? that calls some method of `To` Given `From` to Adapt ? or there exist an well established idiom for that ?

Comment: Write a `D` constructor that takes a `B`, and properly copies the attributes you care about.

Comment: Ya Thats a simple way but I need to take care of all the attributes. everytime I change B I need to change D's copy constructor.

Comment: *shrug* No one said it would be easy. Or pleasant. If what you need is a dynamic language, then you should be using a dynamic language.

Comment: +1 Hmm I I hate labour. I thought It would be done with a little mind tricks.

Comment: @user256007: Your constructor can be something like `D(const B &b) : B(b) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

Reconstructing a base object to a Derived object is generally not possible. First of all, The allocation only allocated enought space for B and not for D. If you allocated enought space for a D to create the B object (which you currently didn't, and is a bit hard to do anyway), then you could use hacks to 'reconstruct' a object like this :

```
// EXTREME HACK, BE CAREFUL, AND USE WITH CARE
// IF YOU DON'T UNDERSTAND IT, DON'T USE IT.
// you should have allocated (sizeof (D)) space to your b pointer.
D* d_object = new (b) D(B(*b));
// you should consider any previous pointer pointing toward the old B* as dangling.
```

Comment: Whilst this may work, it would be easier, clearer and less error-prone just to do `D *d = new D(*b);`.

Comment: You need to have a copy constructor on `D` that takes `B`

Comment: i figured that it has to be there for the sake of completeness. Might be useful to someone else ending there from google

Answer (score -1):

b points to an object of type  B. It can't become a D. If you want a D, you have to allocate one and copy the fields from *b.

Never think of things from a PHP perspective unless you're writing something in PHP. Never write anything in PHP.

Comment: Its kind of wired to model C++ compromised for PHP. But the thing is If it has a solution with C++ then and only then it has a solution in any other language. and if it has no solution in C++ it has no solution in anything else.

Comment: It *does have* a solution in C++. It just doesn't have a naive solution as you've given.